# Multiple requests with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

As I can make multiple requests with Angular. I have an array and I need to hit the APi n times based on the number of items in the array, however, the correct one, I would wait for the response of a request to call the next one.

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
for(let i in this.arr){
      if(this.arr[i].srcImage){
        ImageSource.fromAsset(this.arr[i].srcImage).then(image => {
          const base64 = image.toBase64String('jpeg')

          this.setDamageReportConfirmUseCase.execute([{ srcImage: base64 }])
          .pipe()
          .subscribe((damagesReport) => {​
            console.log('DAMAGES REPORT', `I is ${i}. count is ${this.elementStep.filter(item => item.srcImage).length}`)
          })
        })
      }
```

***damage-report-confirm-data.repository.ts***

```
public setDamageReportConfirm(params: DamageReportConfirmFilterParamModel[]): Observable<DamageReportWizardStepsModel[]> {
    const id = getNumber('id')
    const image = params[0].srcImage
    return this.http
    .post<Array<DamageReportConfirmFilterParamModel>>(`${environment.host}/image`,
    {image})
    .pipe(map(this.damageReportConfirmDataMapper.from))
  }
```

Comment: Can you put more details in what is your Question here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below code.

Note : I have used `async` `await` here.
Request observables can be conveniently handled with promises in Angular.

I am asuming ImageSource.fromAsset returns a promise.

also check `.toPromise()` method on observable

```
async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
        const result1 = await ImageSource.fromAsset(this.arr[i].srcImage);
        const base64 = result1.toBase64String('jpeg')
        const result2 = await this.setDamageReportConfirmUseCase.execute([{ srcImage: base64 }]).toPromise();

       ... // rest of you code 
      }
    } catch (err) { ... }
  }
```

else using observable you can do something like :

import range from rxjs.

```
range(1, 100).map(i =>
      this.dataCallService.firstAPI(data1)
      .concatMap(() => this.dataCallService.secondAPI(data2))
    })
    .concatAll()
    .subscribe(res => {});
```